# Helm rollback to previous build is not reflecting in deployments

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to rollback the helm chart to the previous build using the below command.

`helm rollback service_name --debug -n namespace`

In helm history, it showing rollback updated.

`helm history service_name -n namespace`

`62              Fri Sep 10 14:11:07 2021        deployed        service_name-0.1.0        1.16.0          Rollback to 60`

But POD is not updating, Still it showing the old build id, Even after manual restarts.

Comment: Are there any more details you can provide about this setup?  For example, how does the build ID get passed through from running `helm upgrade` down into the pod manifest?

Comment: @DavidMaze - As of now I am not passing any build ID details to the helm command, I thought helm maintains all the build details in the form of a configmap so it will pick build details from that?

Comment: I am using the CI/CD pipeline to build the docker image and using artifacts i am passing the build ID.

Comment: In your Deployment spec, what is the `image:`?  Can you provide a [mcve], in particular noting the complete Helm command and values you use both on the initial install and the upgrade?

Comment: @DavidMaze
1)Building the docker image and pushing it to the container registry.
2)In helm deployment configuration i am specifying: gcr.io/project_name/folder_name/service_name:latest
3)Then deploying helm charts using 
helm upgrade --install service_name service_name -f ./service_name/values.yaml -f ./service_name/values-dev.yaml --set image.tag=latest
4)Once it's deployed, I am trying to roll back the service using the below command.
helm rollback service_name --debug -n namespace

Comment: Avoid using a `latest` tag in Kubernetes.  As far as Helm can tell, the old and new Deployment objects are identical, so nothing gets submitted to the cluster; at the cluster level, the Deployment already has _n_ Pods that are running `image: ...:latest` so nothing needs to change.  `--set image.tag=...` something unique per build, maybe the source control commit ID.

Comment: (This applies on `helm rollback` too: version 62 wanted `image: ...:latest` and so did version 60, so nothing gets sent to the cluster.  Beyond that `--set` value Helm has no idea what `latest` might correspond to.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your help.
It's working after adding build ID instead of the latest.